# Changing an html attribute based on its current value in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I feel like I'm trying to do something fairly straightforward, but I can't seem to figure out how. I have a page displaying several bar graphs, and I'm trying to build a button that makes certain bars appear and disappear. The bars have labels, and when the button is toggled, I want half the bars to dissappear, the remaining bars to double in size and the labels for the bars to move down a little bit.

I'm using D3.js to draw my graphs, and I've got almost everything working, except these little labels. All I'm trying to do is increment their "y" attribute by about 15 pixels, but I can't seem to find a way to request this value before changing it!

Initially I thought

```
d3.selectAll(".bar-value-label").attr("y", function(d,i){ return d + 15;})
```

should work. However, when I logged what this "d" was, it turned out to be a reference to the data object initially used to create this element.

So, basically I'm just trying to find a way to get the current value and in- or decrement it. Is there a nice way to do this within D3?

Regards,
Linus

EDIT: 
Okay, so I've found a way that works. I'm very doubtfull that this is the best/most efficient way, so answers are still very much welcome :)

```
            var resp_labels = d3.selectAll(".bar-value-label-resp")[0];
            resp_labels.forEach(function(d,i){
              var old_y = parseFloat(d.getAttribute("y"));
              d3.select(d).transition().attr("y", function(i){ return old_y - barheight/4 ;});
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to check that it works, but I think that this is a slightly simplified version of your solution:

```
var resp_label = d3.select(".bar-value-label-resp");
var old_y = +resp_label.attr("y");
resp_label.transition().attr("y", old_y - barheight/4);
```